# алгоритм получения нужных данных

Tags: php, алгоритм, curl, сеть

Есть массив целевых url

`$urlArray = array('aaa','bbb','xxx','yyy','zzz');`

Размер массива заранее неизвестен.
Так же имеется массив прокси серверов

`$proxyArray = array('iii','jjj','kkk');`

Размер этого массива также не известен.

Задача состоит в том что бы с максимальной вероятностью получить 200 http_code для всех url из массива $urlArray с использованием параллельных запросов curl и прокси.

На ум приходит такое решение: зациклить запросы с дальнейшим исключением из массива url по которым был ответ 200, по мере уменьшения массива с url, назначать один и тот же url нескольким прокси серверам, до тех пор пока массив с url не останется пуст.
Проблема в том что этим решением очень сильно нагружается целевой сервер: на один url будет приходить несколько запросов. Возможно подскажите более правильное решение?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что нагрузка на целевой сервер будет настолько мизерной, что он ее даже не почувствует.

Но, если все же хочется, то оптимальным вариантом будет использование вложенного цикла.

```
$urlArray = array('aaa','bbb','xxx','yyy','zzz');
$proxyArray = array('iii','jjj','kkk');
$out = array();

foreach($urlArray as $url){
    foreach($proxyArray as $proxy){
        ....
        if($retCode == 200) {
            $out[] = $url;
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($out as $url){
    if(!in_array($url, $urlArray)) echo "Bad URL: ".$url.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: в теории возможен вариант что на один url будет 'ломится' несколько тысяч прокси